# ¿Como transformar números a letras con php?

Tags: php

En php 5.1 -
Quisiera saber si actualmente alguien conoce alguna función en donde pueda convertir mis números a palabras, por ejemplo:

```
$numero = "1200";
$conversion = "mil doscientos soles";
```

o también:

```
$numero = "0.25";
$conversion = "cero , veinticinco soles";
```

o también:

```
$numero = "1000500";
$conversion = "un millon quinientos soles";
```

o también:

```
$numero = "10500.25";
$conversion = diez mil quinientos , veinticinco soles";
```

Comment: Veo que ya tienes reputación en SO. Eso significa que ya sabes que las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta.

Comment: Existe un paquete de Pear llamado `Nums_Words` que es para eso, [ver aquí](https://pear.php.net/package/Numbers_Words), es lo más simple y completo que hay. Luego, hay librerías particulares que se han creado, por ejemplo [esta](https://github.com/ivanovsaleksejs/NumToText/blob/master/NumToText.php). Y muchas otras que se han propuesto en preguntas de SO en Inglés, ver por ejemplo [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/277569/5587982) y sus respuestas, así como las preguntas enlazadas.

Comment: @Alfabravo gracias estimado, intente buscar algo para php y no encontré nada, es por aquello que consulto directamente si alguien posee alguna función.

Comment: @FranciscoAcevedo este es el tipo de preguntas en las que suele ser divertido meterse en la documentación e intentarlo uno mismo. Es el tipo de cosas que te lanzan encima en las entrevistas :)

Comment: @Alfabravo gracias nuevamente.

Comment: @A.Cedano muchas gracias , revisare la documentación enviada :)

Answer (score 16):

No se si esto es para un ejercicio o para un problema real. Si es para un ejercicio supongo que el profesor lo que quiere es que lo implementes tú recorriendo cada dígito, con su bucle for, etc.

Si lo que necesitas es una solución sin reeinventar la rueda para un programa real puedes utilizar un NumberFormatter (disponible desde PHP 5.3) para obtener el texto en el idioma que necesites:

```
$formatterES = new NumberFormatter("es", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
echo $formatterES->format(123.45);
$formatterDE = new NumberFormatter("de", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
echo $formatterDE->format(123.45);
```

La salida es:

```
ciento veintitrés coma cuatro cinco
ein­hundert­drei­und­zwanzig Komma vier fünf
```

EDIT: Jugando un poco con la función puedes evitar que te ponga "coma cuatro cinco" y que ponga "coma cuarenta y cinco":

```
$formatterES = new NumberFormatter("es-ES", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
$n = 123.45;
$izquierda = intval(floor($n));
$derecha = intval(($n - floor($n)) * 100);
echo $formatterES->format($izquierda) . " coma " . $formatterES->format($derecha);
// ciento veintitrés coma cuarenta y cinco
```

Más información:

- https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.numberformatter.php

Comment: Me sorprendió que hubiese una manera nativa de hacerlo sin el uso de librerías externas. Me la apunto, nunca se sabe :)

Comment: muy bien, lo implementare y te cuento ;)

Comment: Pero esto no resuelve el problema como es requerido. La salida deseada sería: `ciento veintitrés coma **cuarenta y cinco**`. No sé si `NumberFormatter` tenga otras opciones o configuraciones que permitan lograr esto.

Comment: @A.Cedano he añadido una posible solución

Comment: Excelente aporte.

Comment: tengo el siguiente error : `Fatal error: Class 'NumberFormatter' not found in`

Comment: @FranciscoAcevedo ¿Qué versión de PHP usas? debería estar disponible de PHP 5.3.0 en adelante: https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.numberformatter.php

Comment: @FranciscoAcevedo, para activar/instalar la extension lee [estos comentarios](https://www.php.net/manual/es/intl.installation.php#114933)

Comment: @ordago estoy usando php 5.1 creo que no es compatible :(

Comment: @FranciscoAcevedo efectivamente, la clase NumberFormatter está disponible desde PHP 5.3. Edito mi respuesta para añadir ese dato, gracias.

Answer (score 4):

**Claro que si existe varias librerias que hacen esta funcion.**

te recomiendo que visites esta libreria en el link de https://packagist.org

https://packagist.org/packages/luecano/numero-a-letras

Tambien he realizado un video como instalar es libreria en mi canal de youtube. el cual te puede ayudar a instalarlo y usarla.

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3cOyxLxHbA&t=68s
```

Te recomiendo para usarla tener conocimientos previos del uso del composer para su instalacion:

1) instalar composer:
2) tipear composer init
3) tipear composer require   (para usar el asistente y colocar la libreria)
4) agregar el autoloader
5) probar la libreria.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php

// se llama desde una subcarpeta
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

// usando paquete 
use NumeroALetras\NumeroALetras;

$a='<h1>Saludos</h1>';
echo $a;
echo NumeroALetras::convertir(99.99, 'soles');
?>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, precisamente necesito esto para procesar facturación electrónica en "peru"  :)  nose si sera necesario este texto en la facturación electrónica para peru, pero necesito tenerlo en caso de que sea obligatorio.

Comment: será compatible con php 5.1 ? recién debo retomar este tema, lo había hecho con js

Answer (score 3):

Como aportación, con esta adaptación se puede mejorar el alcance de `NumberFormatter`.

Podemos pasar los parámetros a la función para un determinado nombre como `pesos`, `centavos` y una conjunción como `y`, `con`, etc.

Es una función básica que se podría mejorar para adaptarla a otras situaciones.

```
function number_words($valor,$desc_moneda, $sep, $desc_decimal) {
     $arr = explode(".", $valor);
     $entero = $arr[0];
     if (isset($arr[1])) {
         $decimos = strlen($arr[1]) == 1 ? $arr[1] . '0' : $arr[1];
     }

     $fmt = new \NumberFormatter('es', \NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
     if (is_array($arr)) {
         $num_word = ($arr[0]>=1000000) ? "{$fmt->format($entero)} de $desc_moneda" : "{$fmt->format($entero)} $desc_moneda";
         if (isset($decimos) && $decimos > 0) {
             $num_word .= " $sep  {$fmt->format($decimos)} $desc_decimal";
         }
     }
     return $num_word;
}
```

**Algunas pruebas:**

```
echo number_words("10.10","pesos","y","centavos");
echo number_words("10","pesos","y","centavos");
echo number_words("1000000","pesos","y","centavos");
echo number_words("0.25","pesos","y","centavos");
echo number_words("500.35","dólares","con","centavos");
```

Salida:

```
diez pesos y diez centavos
diez pesos
un millón de pesos
cero pesos y veinticinco centavos
quinientos dólares con treinta y cinco centavos
```

---

#### Fuente

Este código es una adaptación de [esta fuente](https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/NumberFormatter/format/php-numberformatter-format-method-examples.html#0x7c5d98024d0e51a1af449dbfe6931ccea93737bb1dc5a644be0c3a21508a43df-39,,64,), con manejos específicos para el español, como es el caso de los millones.

Comment: es exactamente lo que necesito, lo pruebo y te comento.

Comment: me da el siguiente error: `Fatal error: Class 'NumberFormatter' not found`

Comment: @FranciscoAcevedo parece que tu PHP no viene con `NumberFormatter`. ¿Podrías decirnos qué versión de PHP tienes y qué sistema operativo estás usando?

Comment: Tengo PHP 5.1  , ahora debo retomar el tema, ya que lo había implementado con js