# Pasar un numero a texto

Tags: php

Buen día, estoy haciendo una función para convertir un numero en cadena, pero por la forma en la que me piden hacerlo se me complica un poco, el número lo obtengo de la siguiente función:

```
public function getReciboPago()
{
    $recibo_pago = $this->entity->getJSONOperacion($this->id_caja_operacion);
    $datos_ticket = json_decode($recibo_pago['datos_ticket']);

    return $this->helper->numberF($datos_ticket->monto_total);
}
```

datos_ticket es la variable a la que se le asigna el valor de monto_total.

Ejemplo:
monto_total me regresará 240.00 
El método que haré tendrá que regresar "Docientos cuarenta"

Agradecería mucho su ayuda, gracias.

Comment: No esta claro que es lo que necesitas hacer, si convertir (_por ejemplo_) `"123"` a `123` u obtener la representación en palabras, es decir, `ciento veintitres`. Por favor, edita tu pregunta y aclara exactamente que es lo que necesitas, da un ejemplo y el resultado esperado.

Comment: @Marcos ya edité la pregunto, agregué el ejemplo.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Como transformar números a letras con php?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/301584/16597)

Comment: Okey, lo checaré, gracias.