# Convertir números a letras en jaspersoft Studio

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Estoy realizando una factura en Jasper y necesito pasar el monto total a letras(10 = diez). Por ejemplo en Crystal Reports es funcion ToWords, busqué mucho en la web y casi no hay nada.
Les dejo una imagen de lo que estoy realizando. Los campos están acomodados a una factura física que se utiliza actualmente y quizás parezca todo desordenado. Gracias y saludos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la librería ICU4J, la cual puedes importar con esta dependencia de Maven:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.icu/icu4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
    <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
    <version>69.1</version>
</dependency>
```

El uso es muy sencillo, creas una regla de formato indicando el locale del idioma que quieras usar usando el tipo de formato "SPELLOUT" y después llamas al método format de la regla para dar formato de texto al número que quieras escribir.

```
RuleBasedNumberFormat rule = new RuleBasedNumberFormat(new Locale("es-ES"), RuleBasedNumberFormat.SPELLOUT);
System.out.println(rule.format(10)); // Escribe "diez"
```

Más información:

- https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/icu4j/

Cómo hacer lo mismo en PHP:

- [¿Como transformar números a letras con php?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/301584/como-transformar-n%c3%bameros-a-letras-con-php/301591#301591)

Comment: Hola ordago°!! gracias por contestar, ahora mi pregunta de fuego es donde inserto esos datos que me has proveído? Disculpas por eso, pero no manejo mucho esta magnífica herramienta.